# Error .No input file specified how can i fix it?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is URL kingmaddy.me/adm http://kingmaddy.me/signup i cant access

here is my htaccess file

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase //

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# List of files in subdirectories will not be displayed in the browser
Options -Indexes

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
 AddCharset UTF-8 .htm .html .txt
 AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" .htm .html .txt
 AddType "text/css; charset=UTF-8" .css
 AddType "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8" .js

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

note  RewriteEngine is On

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I had the error "No input file specified" and I solved it changing the file name. It was because the name contained the "ñ" symbol. Maybe you have another invalid character in the name.

I hope I help someone.